# Copy local files in Hadoop File System

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

What is the fastest way to copy files in HDFS in programmatic way ? I have tried for DistCp but couldn't get the appropriate content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
 fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("/home/me/localdirectory/"),   new Path("/me/hadoop/hdfsdir"));
```

DistCp works only intra-cluster (from hdfs to hdfs).

Comment: Is it fast enough to copy the content of a huge file in less time ?

Comment: Depends on your hardware. HDDs operate at ~50-150MB/sec, ethernet 1Gb/sec. That's the speed limit.

Comment: This will only be ok for reasonably small data set (few GB). A more scalable approach would be to use distcp in order to distribute the load across the cluster (read and write from multiple nodes).

Comment: As per my knowledge and as Jerome said, DistCp works for both

Answer (score 2):

**distcp** works perfectly fine for both **localfFS to HDFS** and **HDFS to HDFS** copying. However, it doesn't provide us the benefit of high parallelism of MapReduce since the input data resides on localFS(a non-distributes store) and not on HDFS. So, using either of the two will give you almost the same performance, which obviously depends on the hardware and size of input data.

BTW, what do you mean by **DistCp but couldn't get the appropriate content**?

Comment: My mean I searched for the programming stuff for DistCp but even APIs are not described over Inernet

Comment: Have you tried copying from localFS to HDFS? It goes fine in single-node mode, but I face FileNotFoundException on a real cluster. I do hadoop distcp file:///home/user/myfile.txt hdfs:///tmp/. It says: ... FileNotFound: file:/home/user/myfile.txt. I assume it tries to find file in local FS on the node the map is run on.

Answer (score 0):

Distcp is certainly the fastest way to copy large amount of data over HDFS. I would suggest to try first from the command line before calling if from your favorite programming language.

```
hadoop distcp -p -update "hdfs://A:8020/user/foo/bar" "hdfs://B:8020/user/foo/baz"
```

-p to preserve status, -update to overwrite data if a file is already present but has a different size.

Since Distcp is [written in Java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-tools/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/tools/DistCp.java), you shouldn't have any difficulty to call it from a Java application. You can also use your favorite script language (Python, bash, etc.) to run hadoop distcp like any other command line application.